# getGEO R Program

Tags: r, bioconductor

Good Afternoon Everyone,

I have been using R Program, Bioconductor, and GEO Query to analyze some NCBI GEO Microarray Datasets for a few months now.

The current R Program Versions I have been using have been Version 3.4.1 and Version 3.4.4. The Bioconductor Version that has been available for use for this R Program versions on my personal computer and laboratory computer is Bioconductor 3.6.

I have been experiencing a problem with using the "getGEO" command function in the R Program. Whenever I load all of the required packages needed, update all of the sources according to the request of the R program,   and then try to use getGEO to upload the microarray expression set (both GDS and GSE Series Matrix/SOFT Family Files), the R Program responds back saying that the "getGEO function" cannot be found.

This problem started yesterday evening and has never happened to me while using GEOQuery, Bioconductor, or R Program.

I have typed out my coding below:

```
source("http://www.bioconductor.org/biocLite.R")
biocLite()
biocLite("GEOquery")
library(GEOQuery)
getPackageIfNeeded <- function(pkg){if(!require(pkg,character.only = TRUE))biocLite(pkgs=pkg)}
sapply(pkgs,getPackageIfNeeded)
library(Biobase)
library(limma)
library(affy)
gset <- getGEO("GSE69033", GSEMatrix =TRUE)
gse <- getGEO("GSE69033", GSEMatrix =TRUE)
```

Questions:

1. Was there some kind of program update with R Program to where the getGEO function does not work anymore with Bioconductor or GEOQuery?
2. Is there something wrong with my scripting or coding? Is there something missing or is there something that is not supposed to be there?
3. Is there another way to upload NCBI GEO Microarray Datasets into R Program without the getGEO function?
4. Do any of you recommend any Gene Expression Analysis Techniques from MATLAB or Python? If so, could you mention a link to a coding script for either of those software programs?

Any help or direction in regards to my questions would be greatly appreciated. Thank you so much and I am very glad to be a part of this forum.

Comment: Do you not get any error message after `library(GEOQuery)`? When you get your error, what does `sessionInfo()` show (it should list all the loaded packages)?

Comment: I did get an error message that mentioned library (GEOQuery) being incorrect, but I did not know that it was talking about the sensitive casing. I tried to use the correct code of library(GEOquery) and the program starting working. Thank you for your input. I will also try "sessionInfo()" just to see how it works. Does you recommend learning or trying anything else that could reduce mistakes in the R-Program especially with regards to sensitive casing? Thank you again and much success in your coding, programming, and developing endeavors!